# Maven won't package java project

Tags: maven, jar

I'm attempting to make a .jar of my java maven project. The project itself is a helloworld project so I won't post the actual java code. The project name is test
Here's the test/pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>serge</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.mkyong.core.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here's the error I'm getting when I run `mvn -e package test`:

```
serge@serge-B353:~/Documents/workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE$ mvn -e package test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [package, test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cannot execute mojo: resources. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but     the build is not using one.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Cannot execute mojo: resources. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.ja    va:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycl    eExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.jav    a:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLife    cycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExec    utor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:18    0) 
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot execute mojo: resources.    It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.
at     org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:414)
at     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 26 20:52:36 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/74M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Apologies for the bad formatting, I was able to format the xml no issues, but the error trace won't budge. Any tips on this as well?

Comment: To format the console output you just needed to add a blank line between the console output and the line before.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured out what my particular issue was, but I would think my previous approach should work too.

I was running the command outside of the project folder('test' in this case). Once I navigated inside the folder and ran mvn package it generated the .jar in the target folder.

Previously I was trying to pass the project to the package command in this manner:

```
mvn package test
```

Comment: Which could not work. `mvn package test` would try to run first to the package, and afterwards again to the test phase. What would have worked (assuming test is the project name) would be: `mvn package -f test/pom.xml`